# AngularJS - I want to open a new page with user details

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, frontend

I have a view that shows a list of users, and i want to open a User Details page, when the user clicks on the link.

It loads the "Users.html" page, when I click on the href, the URL on browser changes, but it doesn't load the template for User Detail, also the console doesn't have any errors.

Here is my ng-repeat code:

```
 <div class="lista-dicas" ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'-ID'">
        <div class="col-md-12 box-noticia">
            <h3 class="titulo"><a ui-sref="app.users.id({id: user.ID})">{{ user.ID }}</a></h3>
            <p class="subtitulo">{{ user.Name }}</p>
            <p class="tags">{{ user.Tags }}</p>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My router configs

```
angular.module('myapp_dicas').config(routeConfig);

function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('app.users', {
    url: '/users',
    templateUrl: '/www/app/users/users.html',
    controller: 'UsersController'
  })
  .state('app.users.id', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'www/app/users/user-detail.html',
    controller: 'UserDetailController'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
url: '/:id',
```

To

```
url: '/users/details/:id',
```

Ok, cause it didn't work, do you have `app` state? If not, try to change state names to, for example, `users` and `details` (just like this, no dots). Cause now, it looks like `id` state is child of `users` and it may cause a problem. And URL for details: `url: '/users/details/:id',` cause it looks natural.

Comment: It didnt worked. The URL changed to users/users/detail/id and the template does not load.